# Perfomance Difference between = and LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have found that `LIKE` will take more execution time then `=` operator.

```
select * from `texts` where `letter` like 'a';
```

The above query with `LIKE` parameter will take 3 microsecond for execute.

```
select * from `texts` where `letter`='a';
```

The above query with `=` parameter will take 1 microsecond for execute.

Is there any difference between them?

Check [**<kbd>SQL Fiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe857/2)

Comment: *microsecond* The difference could simply be noise. Try running it with a decent amount of data.

Comment: I give just sample data If table contains Millions of records then It may be effect on perfomance.

Comment: @Sadikhasan . . . I didn't downvote, but the difference between 1 and 3 microseconds is noise.  You should run tests on millions of rows to check the performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `LIKE` is case-insensitive - this is ofcourse bound to take some processing time **per row**. In addition to that, setting up the query (e.g. parsing the argument to `LIKE` for wildcards) takes another few moments **per query**.

The most important part: `LIKE` will in most cases be unable to use an index, so be prepared for more execution time (by orders of magnitude) on larger tables with queries of a high selectivity.

**Edit**

As @Ravinder pointed out, on default collation the `=` operator is NOT case sensitive.

Comment: What you mean by `LIKE is case-insensitive` also `=` is also case-insensitive

Comment: I beg to diagree: Try `select 'A'='a', 'A' LIKE 'a';`

Comment: Unless you go with `binary` it is always case insensitive both on `equals` and `like`.

Comment: @Ravinder ... ah, I allways have `collation-server=utf8_bin` on my servers, so this ofcourse differs. Will edit answer to mention that.